# Determine $ \ \large \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{40-2^{-0.1x+5} \sin (x)}{5-\frac{1}{x}} \ $

Tags: limits

Determine $ \ \large \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{40-2^{-0.1x+5} \sin (x)}{5-\frac{1}{x}} \ $

**Answer:**

$ \ \large \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{40-2^{-0.1x+5} \sin (x)}{5} \\ = \ \large \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{40}{5-\frac{1}{x}}- \ \large \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2^{-0.1x+5} \sin (x)}{5-\frac{1}{x}} \\ =8 - \frac{0 \cdot \lim_{x \to \infty} \sin (x}{5-0} \\ =8-0 \\ =8$

**Am I right?**

Comment: I don't see any mistakes. And I put it in Wolfram Alpha and it says 8 as well.

Comment: No, I think. Limit of the product is the product of limits provided that both limits exist

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan What are you reffering to?

Comment: @Chiray Remember that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin x$ does not exist.

Comment: But $sin(x)$ is bounded, so that shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: @Chiray Yeah, I know. The way the OP present his solution is not correct.

Comment: @Chiray He wrote as $$\lim_{x\to\infty}2^{-0.1x+5}\sin x=0\cdot\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin x.$$ You think it is correct?

Comment: No, you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my comments above. You are almost correct. Better argue as follows. Note that
as $x\to +\infty$ we have $$0\leq |2^{-0.1x+5}\sin x|\leq 2^{-0.1x+5}\to 0.$$
This implies (using the Squeeze Theorem) that $$\lim_{x\to +\infty} 2^{-0.1x+5}\sin x=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right:
$$ \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{40-2^{-0.1x+5} \sin (x)}{5-\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{40-\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{32\sin{x}}{2^{0.1x}}}{5-\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{1}{x}}=8$$